# pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure because of encrypted password from PAM stack

Tags: ldap, sssd

To configure sssd to connect AD server.
I set id_provider to ldap

As AD server cannot accept TLS, so I closed it by:

1. ldap_id_use_start_tls = false
2. set ssl off in ldap.conf

When I use login ftp via domain account, it works. But it failed for ssh.

I compared the TCPdump between ftp and ssh. I found the password are different in bindrequest between ftp and ssh. It seems ssh encrypted the password, so that pam_sss got the wrong password from PAM stack.

Encrypted Password as below:
simple: \b\n\r\177INCO

If it's possible to change it to plaintext password for ssh?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing here isn't an encrypted password, it's from sshd, specifically:

```
const char junk[] = "\b\n\r\177INCORRECT";
```

Before sshd tries to authenticate with PAM, it calls getpwnam() to check if the user is valid.  If not, it'll replace the entered password with a portion of the junk string, then validate the user/junk password with PAM.

What (I'm fairly certain) ended up being my problem was nscd.  When I stopped that service, getpwnam worked, and the correct password was sent to the LDAP backend.  I had nscd already installed, and without a restart, it was not checking LDAP for user queries.  An easy way to test getpwnam calls from the command line would be to run `id username` or `getent passwd username`.  But be careful, running `getent passwd` and looking for an expected username will work, even when the user-specific commands don't.

Comment: Your answer appears to me like you were the person who did the original question. Should that really be the case, you should visit https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).